# Cannot Get Flow to Work in HTML Form using PHP

Tags: php, function

I am trying to use HTML to get a number from the user in one page, execute a function based on that number in a PHP doc and show the results of that function on a third page. The code is shown below in chronological order.

index.php

```
 <h3>A bit about your company, please.</h3>

 <p>What was your net operating income for Q4 of 2014?</p>
 <form action="calc.php">
 <input type="text" name="noi">
 <input type="submit" value="Submit">
 </form>
```

calc.php

```
 $profit = $_POST['noi'];

 function makeProfit () {
 if ($profit >='0') {
    echo "Your company is making a profit.";
    }
 }
 header("Location: viewpage.php");
```

viewpage.php

```
 include'calc.php';

 makeProfit();
```

The error message I get when I type a number into the HTML form and click submit is "This page has a redirect loop" on viewpage.php, skipping calc.php altogether. Any help would be sincerely appreciated. I tried to start off small to keep it simple but I'm obviously missing something that's probably quite obvious, it's been a while since I last coded PHP.

Comment: You include calc.php which redirects to viewpage.php which includes calc.php which redirects to viewpage.php  which includes calc.php which redirects to viewpage.php  which includes calc.php which redirects to viewpage.php  which includes calc.php which redirects to viewpage.php which includes calc.php which redirects to viewpage.php  which includes calc.php which redirects to viewpage.php  which includes calc.php which redirects to viewpage.php  which includes calc.php which redirects to viewpage.php  which includes calc.php which redirects to viewpage.php. Get it?

Comment: *Oh by the wayyyyyy...* `<form action="calc.php">` <= that defaults to GET.

Comment: If you wish to traverse to more than two pages, you will need sessions if you want to use pure PHP. Plus, you say: *"execute a function based on that number"* - I'm not entirely sure what you mean by that and could be quite broad. If the user enters the number 10 let's say; should there be a function to execute it based on that number? You're going to need to be a bit more precise.

Comment: More precisely, based on the amount of profit I intend to code a recommender system which will issue different recommendations based on the profit and/or lack thereof. I have removed the header redirect and replaced it with makeProfit(); but it just lingers on calc.php without echoing any statement.

Comment: You're getting a redirection loop because calc.php contains a header to go to viewpage.php then you're including calc.php in the viewpage.php file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few problems here.

Firstly, your form in index.php is missing a POST method.

Forms default to GET when the method is omitted, and you're using `$_POST['noi']` in calc.php, therefore that will fail silently.

Then you're comparing and checking for a string rather than an integer using `>='0'` in calc.php

When an integer is entered, it will always evaluate to FALSE, therefore that needs to be `>=0`

In regards to your headers: Remove them. You're stuck in an endless loop.

You're getting a redirection loop because calc.php contains a header to go to viewpage.php then you're including calc.php in the viewpage.php file.

I suggest you do the following:

**index.php** would contain:

```
<h3>A bit about your company, please.</h3>

 <p>What was your net operating income for Q4 of 2014?</p>
 <form action="calc.php" method="post">
 <input type="text" name="noi">
 <input type="submit" value="Submit">
 </form>
```

**calc.php** and "echo" the function while checking if a number was indeed used, and not a string using [`is_numeric()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-numeric.php).

```
<?php 

if(is_numeric($_POST['noi'])){
// use int if you want to use integers
// $profit = (int)$_POST['noi'];

 $profit = $_POST['noi'];
}

else{
echo "Enter a number only.";
exit;
}

 function makeProfit () {
 if ($profit >= 0) {
    echo "Your company is making a profit.";
    }

else{
echo "No profit was made.";
}

 }
 include 'viewpage.php';
```

You need to include "viewpage.php", and not a header for it. Otherwise you will get the following error:

> Fatal error: Call to undefined function makeProfit()...

**viewpage.php** - Sidenote: You need to echo the function.

```
<?php 
echo makeProfit();
```

---

***Sidenote about "calc.php":***

I suggest you use the following instead, because making a profit means more than zero.

`>= 0` has been changed to `> 0`.

Therefore entering "0" will always be a profit; I don't think this is what you want and on the business side of things, doesn't make sense.

The following will also accept the following: 0.1, .1, 1.25 etc.

```
<?php 

 function makeProfit () {

    if(is_numeric($_POST['noi'])){

     $profit = $_POST['noi'];

    }

    else{
    echo "Enter a number only.";
    exit;
    }

 if ($profit > 0) {

    echo "Your company is making a profit.";
    }

    else{
    echo "No profit";
    }

 }

 include 'viewpage.php';
```

Comment: @MatthieuMcClintock So, did this in fact solve it, or is this question still considered open?

Answer (score 0):

In this current setup,  viewpage.php is not required.   You should remove that header() redirect.

edit:
so now you're submitting your form, and it's arriving at the page, but it's not running your function.  either just run the function using makeProfit() or don't keep that code inside a function.   there are a few other issues with your stuff here, but I don't want to rewrite it for you.

Comment: Ok. I removed header redirect and added makeProfit(); to calc.php and now it just lingers on an empty page.